# If user is logged in, show a theme, if not show no theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to do something like this.

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    switch_theme("bone-adless");
} else {
    switch_theme("bone-ads");
};
```

If a user has an account, they get a theme which serves no advertisements on my site, but if they're not signed in they have a theme which displays advertisements.

This above code should be working, but doesn't, what can I do to make it work?

Comment: Could you explain what happens when the code is not working? What theme does the user see?

Comment: @kost it just shows the Bone-Adless theme regardless if logged in or not.

Comment: you need to add this in `init` hook

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can switch theme in Wordpress.

```
add_action( 'setup_theme', 'switch_user_theme' );
function switch_user_theme() {
  if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    switch_theme('twentytwelve');
  } else {
    switch_theme('twentythirteen');
  }
}
```

other option: 
first you need redirect to user in desire page/location and with template we can Customise its layout